# C# XAML UWP InvalidCastException with MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, xaml, win-universal-app

I can't figure out what's causing this exception. I come from a VB.NET background and C# is giving me a real hard time. Can someone shed some light on this?

```
                using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("server=server;uid=uid;pwd=pwd;database=db;SslMode=None"))
            {
                connection.Open();
                MySqlCommand getCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
                getCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MyId", MyId);
                getCommand.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PhoneTag WHERE MyId = @MyId";
                int userCount = (int)getCommand.ExecuteScalar();
```

}

Comment: int userCount = (int)getCommand.ExecuteScalar(); is causing the exception :(

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I should have been using ExecuteNonQuery()